# Meaning of Java syntax: class A extends B<C>

Tags: java

What does this syntax mean in `Java`: `class A extends B<C>`? I came across this in an Android library and couldn't find it on google.

More specifically, this is what I had come across:

```
public class PullToRefreshExpandableListView extends PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase<ExpandableListView>
```

Comment: Look up Inheritance or read up on Object-oriented programming. This kind of question also does not fit StackOverflow.

Comment: It means that `A` extends a type-specialized version of the generic class `B`. A does not have an "is-a" relationship with B, but it has an "is-a" relationship with B<C>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Generics with Class and Interfaces***
Genrics is one of the core feature of Java programming and it was introduced in Java 5. 
We can define our own classes and interfaces with generics type.

A generic type is a class or interface that is parameterized over types. ***We use angle brackets (<>) to specify the type parameter.***

Please refer [this link](http://www.journaldev.com/1663/java-generics-tutorial-example-class-interface-methods-wildcards-and-much-more) for more information